# Please explain type synonyms

Tags: haskell, yesod, type-families

I am learning so may be this is a trivial question.

In the code generated by yesod scaffolding tool I found this expression:

```
type YesodPersistBackend PersistTest = SqlPersist
```

My understanding is that it creates a parameterised type `YesodPersistBackend` that has one type argument `PersistTest`, and this is equivalent to the type `SqlPersist`.

Is this correct? If so, why would one create a type synonym with parameters for a type that does not have parameters?

Comment: This code isn't valid Haskell. Could you please show us some context to make it easier to see, what it could mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a vanilla type declaration. If you see the full code, it looks something like this -

```
instance YesodPersist PersistTest where
  type YesodPersistBackend PersistTest = SqlPersist
```

This is using an extension to Haskell98 called TypeFamilies. Read about this specific syntax here - http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-families.html#assoc-type-instance